# Flashing display of html div content when using replace child

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div with some picture and text, it has variable length. I load its content from server and using javascript function (replaceChild) to change this content. Everything (about functionality and performance) is ok but it always flashes? How do i resolve it?

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        <!-- some text and img tag in HERE -->
    </div>
</div>
```

javascipt

```
container.element.replaceChild(main.element, old_main.element);
```

Comment: Can you please post some relevant code in your question?

Comment: Where are you referencing your JS in your .html file? If file is being linked to at the body of you <body> can you try put it in your <head>. Suggestion found here: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/avoiding-the-fouc-v3/

Comment: @Pippin: I have many file javascript and i referencing them at the bottom of the <body> tag. If i move it to the <head> tag, i think it will make awful performance?

Comment: as you are replacing content, isn't it the expected behavior that it flashes? For a smoother behavior, you would have to add an animation, like fade in/out for example.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the expected behaviour, based on what you have done.

You could try to use:

Plain Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("main").appendChild(newContent);
```

jQuery:

```
$("#main").append(newContent);
```

newContent can be HTML and it assumes it has an id.

Hope this helps.